# create multiple columns in r

Tags: r, loops, survival-analysis

I want to test different cutoff in survival analysis. Here is my code:

```
for (cutoff in seq(0.001,0.1,by=0.001)){

   os$rna.nor.high= ifelse(os$rna.nor > cutoff, 1, 0)}

fit = survfit(Surv(os$OS,os$os.ce)~os$rna.nor.high)

ggsurvplot(fit, data= os)
```

However, it only returned one picture and only tested `cutoff=0.1`

I think I should add one column (like `os$rna.nor.high` 1-99) in my os data frame every time it tests a new cutoff, but I don't know how to do it....

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop closes rigth after the ifelse condition. Perhaps if you move survfit and ggsurvplot inside the loop it can perform the tests you want and save the graph using ggsave.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I put survfit and ggsurvplot inside the loop. And save the PDF file as you recommended. However, I couldn't open the newly created 99 PDF files, it says Something’s keeping this PDF from opening.

Comment: Here is the new code.                                                                                             
  for (RNA.cutoff in seq(0.001,0.1,by=0.001)){

 os$rna.nor.high= ifelse(os$rna.nor > RNA.cutoff, 1, 0)

 fit= survfit(Surv(os$OS,os$os.ce)~os$rna.nor.high)

 pdf(paste(  RNA.cutoff, ".pdf", sep=""))

 ggsurvplot(fit, data= os) 

 dev.off()
}

Comment: I see two option: 1) wrap ggsurvplot inside a print command ex.: print(ggsurvplot(....)); or 2) use ggsave instead of pdf/dev.off